Linux swap usage
I have 2 different Debian 12 servers running different - but pretty similar (DB, Java) applications.
Both have 16GB RAM and 1GB swap partition.
Both normally have a RAM usage of ~60% (~40% free). No big changes there.
CPU usage is avg 1 out of 8 - so pretty low.
But one uses no swap at all. The other fills up his swap withing 3 days.
It frees it easily with swapoff. And later fills it again after some days when I do swapon again.
There is no problem is the swap is full - but monitoring alerts.
Both have swapiness of 60.
Whats the reason for that??
I would set swapiness to 10 for both - good idea?

Or you could simply disable SWAP altogether. It's not like 1GB is of any use for a 16GB server.
I've been saying this for decades now but SWAP is not necessary. It can be enabled/used when you know for a fact you can run out of physical RAM, that's it. If you never run out of free RAM, there's very little to no reason to enable it.

It got set that way by standard-install-setup. Not more, not less.

Comment it out in /etc/fstab, and live happily ever after.
